# Типы котов, или разные/Разные коты мира

Tags: орфография

Как правильно этот заголовок оформить? Это просто заголовок, а не название чего-то, например книги.

> Типы котов, или разные коты мира.

> Типы котов, или Разные коты мира.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это заголовок, то обязательно с прописной:

***Типы котов, или Разные коты мира***.

«Грамота.ру»:

> добрый день! допустимо ли такое написание фразы (включая запятую и заглавную букву в середине фразы???)
>
> Бесплатный сыр, или Еще раз про демпинг в автостраховании
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Если это заголовок, то именно такое написание правильно. Правило таково: если название состоит из двух частей, соединенных союзом или, то перед союзом ставится запятая, а первое слово второй части пишется с прописной буквы.